# Householder QR Factorization for m by n Matrix (both m>=n and m<n)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Why in all of books I read about numerical linear algebra (e.g. [Matrix Computations by Golub](http://books.google.com/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=PT224) and [Numerical Linear Algebra and Applications by Datta](http://books.google.com/books?id=1V9PbyYGZIIC&pg=PT188) and many others), Householder QR factorization have mentioned only for m by n (m rows and n columns) matrices with $m>=n$? I am looking for a trusty source that explains Householder QR factorization for a general rectangular matrix, not only for $m>=n$. I found [here](http://m2matlabdb.ma.tum.de/download.jsp?MC_ID=3&MP_ID=164) a MATLAB code that produce R for a general matrix, and I can get Q from it. Also MATLAB built-in qr() function produce Q and R for any rectangular matrix. But why authors of that books did not mention it?

Comment: Well, since $R$ is upper triangular, if $m<n$, there is little to be done to the last $n-m$ columns other than multiplying by $Q^T$. That is, factor the first $m$ columns to get a $Q$, then multiply the remaining columns by $Q^T$ to get the desired factorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"...Householder QR factorization have mentioned only for $m$ by $n$ ($m$ rows and $n$ columns) matrices with $m\geq n$..."

That is not true, at least for Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan and others I know about.

It is true that the initial expositions can be a bit simplified.
The reason why these and other authors concentrate more on the case of a full-rank "tall" matrix $A$ is that problems with such matrices just appear more often in practice and are easier to handle and describe, e.g., you don't need to apply any kind of pivoting.

If this is not the case, then you *must* do some sort of pivoting (see, e.g., Section 5.4.1 "Rank Deficiency: QR with Column Pivoting" in the second edition of MatComp and its application in Section 5.7.2 "Underdetermined Systems"). Consider, e.g., that $A$ is "wide", that is, $m<n$ and has full row rank. Even in this case you need to do some pivoting because there's no guarantee that the leading part of $A$ has full rank (as in the other answer).

You can also find a nice treatment of general QR decompositions in the books Matrix Algorithms by Stewart (volume I) and Numerical Methods for Least Squares Problems by Bjorck.

Comment: Just a doubt: I have read `Householder reflection matrices` and `Givens rotation matrices` are orthogonal and hence no permutations necessary(both row, column). However, when matrix $A$ has non-independent columns $R$ will have non-independent column as well. Does that mean, `Householder reflection` method is suffice without `column pivoting`?

Comment: @RusselB If you do not use column pivoting for matrices with less rows than columns, the R-factor does not need to be triangular but will generally have a “staircase” shape. Depends on requirements on the factor. Also, the factorization without column pivoting might be less reliable due to numerical issues (determining what should already be zero and what not).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m<n$ and let $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1 A_2\end{bmatrix}$, where $A_1$ is square. Let $A_1 = Q_1 R_1$ be a QR decomposition of $A_1$, then have
$A = Q_1 \begin{bmatrix} R_1 & Q_1^TA_2\end{bmatrix}$, which is a QR decomposition of $A$.

Comment: In order to get a robust QR factorization for such matrices, you need to do column pivoting even if $A$ has full (row) rank.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: It is good that you pointed that out, I was looking from an 'existence' perspective rather than the numerics...