# QR decomposition of rectangular matrix where rows less than columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to do QR decomposition for a 3 by 4 matrix. Most examples that I am seeing online are instances where rows>columns like 3 by2 and 4 by3. If I do QR for a 3 by 4 matrix, Q will be 3by 4 and R will be 4by4? Or will it be that Q is 3by3 then R will be 3 by 4. I'm reading on things like Thin QR factorisation but I'm getting confused with the dimensions.

Comment: Might be relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/a/679380/27978